# Audit in Low Quality Posts could be improved without being considered spam

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam

I was reviewing the Low Quality Posts and the following are the decisions I can make when something shows up:

[image: Decisions]

Then, the following appeared:

[image: LQP]

After reading the answer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074766/play-youtube-videos-in-roku-channel) and realizing **it was indeed answering the question**, my move was aiming to remove just the spam part and, therefore, clicked on **Edit**.

It turns out this was an audit and the decision makers behind it considered the answer as spam, right away, instead of giving it a second thought and removing just a specific part of it.

*What can be done in this situation?*

Comment: Don't edit spam.  Spammers never write their own post, they just copy/paste it from somewhere else.  You cannot be sure where he stole it from and under what license it was published.

Comment: Do you know of any SO rule targeting this type of problem? From what you tell me it implies when Spam then delete (no matter what).

Comment: Spam is spam, no matter what.

Comment: From meta.se: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited

Comment: That doesn't actually fit our definition of Spam as it *discloses* the poster's affiliation with the product or service they are promoting. Downvotable due to low quality, possibly, but containing an undisclosed affiliation, no.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Unsolicited advertising is spam, even if the author discloses their affiliation with what's posted. "feel free to call us at xxx" is spam.

Comment: @Robert You can disclose your affiliation and the post still be considered spam if you are self-promoting too much and/or when not appropriate. And this looks like a blatant case of spam, IMO.

Comment: @Moritz it wasn't unsolicited, the question was *about* Roku to begin with. Similarly, if I ask a question about WebSphere, getting an answer from IBM promoting their product would not be entirely unsolicited. If Reebok answered with a recommendation for buying their shoes, then yes, that would be Spam.

Comment: He did not disclose anything, that link does not take you to the Roku website.  The original lives on a website that has a wonky association with linkedin.com copyright notices that are impossible to decypher.  And another that was taken down by its service provider, yay.  Just plain spam, spam, spam.

Comment: @RobertColumbia the actual URL hidden behind the text is `my-roku-com-link.com`. The fact the OP is trying to hide that is enough to qualify it as blatant spam IMO.

Comment: @tiagoperes Always make sure you hover over links to make sure they are what they seem. If you had done that, you would have realised why it was considered spam.

Comment: @CalvT i knew that part was spam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is spam.

This is the official website for Roku: `https://www.roku.com`

This is what the answer linked to: [image]

Notice that link text (roku.com) and the actual link differ, something the [Smoke Detector](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/143601) also picked up.

On that website you'll find: *My-roku-com-link.com, Independent guidance provider for Roku devices is not related to Roku.*

So the claim in comments that because they are from Roku and for that reason can post an answer like that seems debunked.

Also the inclusion of an phone-number to dial (or email address for further information) are known tactics for scams / spam. It is spam, it [shouldn't be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited), it should be nuked, you should have reviewed that as "recommend deletion"

Comment: I know that part was Spam, that wasn't my problem. My thought was removing that specific part and the answer becomes viable. What i learned from the comments as well as from your answer is that Spam is spam and should be deleted right away as we don't support spammers.

Comment: Getting a highly reputable SO user to post the spam link is one of the more effective spammer techniques.

Comment: @HansPassant hmm, point. Not sure about the highly reputable ...